# Windows Photo Viewer extreme pixelation for low res images on 1440p native resolution

Tags: windows-11, photos, windows-photo-viewer

Installed Windows 11 and re-enabled Windows Photo Viewer to find out that low-res images (specifically lower than 1285px) become extremely pixelated, to varying degrees, when fully zoomed out / opened in a large window. Doesn't seem to matter if it's .jpg or .png. Even then it's not every image, just most. If it's zoomed in a little, even if it's a super small resolution to begin it, it displays normally. All these images display normally in the Photos App as well.

My drivers are up to date, my Windows is up to date, and I've changed my color profile to the one from my monitor's website (to no notable changes). I've tried fiddling around with AMD graphics settings with no notable difference on anything, and I've done a SFC /scannow. Can't find word on this issue elsewhere. Windows Photo Viewer itself has no settings or options menu so I don't anything to tweak on it. The photos would display normally even if at maximum window size if I dropped my resolution down to 1080p.

Any ideas before I move on to the 3rd party image viewer dive would be appreciated. Really just feels like a legacy application limitation at this point but I hope it isn't.

[image: Pixelated Windows Photo Viewer]

Comment: "re-enabled Windows Photo Viewer" how exactly? It looks like you've grabbed the Windows 7 photos app instead of using the newer built-in application which probably supports modern computers better.

Comment: I would have thought installing an old version of Photo Viewer over a newer one might not be possible. However, even more so, my answer stands:  Back up and install Windows 11 properly.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate all the help and figured out the issue. The issue was I bought my first AMD GPU at a good time for bad drivers. I also learned Window's embedded 'reset Windows' for a 'full clear' install is also a massive lie.
I did actually try reinstalling Windows Photo Viewer manually (deleting and replacing the .dll's taken from my confirmed working PC). Didn't work, of course, but there's methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a clean install and did a step-by-step check for every process to see where it broke. The problem was AMD's latest driver released on 12/05, Adrenalin 23.12.1, breaks Windows Photo Viewer specifically when the entire image can be viewed in its native resolution without resizing.

Installing 23.11.1 ended up subverting the issue and resulted in Windows Photo Viewer displaying normally. I suppose I need to let AMD know about this.